# Regex match a multiline record

Tags: c#, regex

> ID:P1
>  Title:Philips 32PFL4355
>  Description:Experience
>   cinema the way it was meant to be with the state of the art Thinnest
>   Edge LED TV from Philips. Billion display colors and invisible speaker
>   system ensures that you are always a part of every scene.
>   Catgory:LED TVs, Philips-LED TVs
>  Brand:Philips
>  MRP:35890
>   
>  
>  ID:P2
>  Title:Philips 40PFL4356
>  Description:Experience
>   cinema the way it was meant to be with the state of the art Thinnest
>   Edge LCD TV from Philips. Billion display colors and invisible speaker
>   system ensures that you are always a part of every scene.
>   Catgory:LCD TVs, Philips-LCD TVs
>  Brand:Philips
>  MRP:55890

The above example data has two records(record can be multiple lines(per record can be 2 lines or n lines)). Record delimiter is two enter `\n\n`.

My Requirement: Search the keyword (i.e. `LCD`) and select entire record with a regular expression.

Comment: What programming language? What have you tried? This question seems a lot "do the work for me".

Comment: P.S. This is **NOT SPAM**. I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the .NET variety of RegEx, this should get you close:

```
(?<=^|\r\n\r\n)
(.|\n(?!\r))*?
LCD
(.|\n(?!\r))*
(?=\r\n\r\n|$)
```

Join the lines together, of course.

Line 1 establishes you want to start your match immediately at the beginning of the string or where a new record begins.

Line 2 matches the part of the record that can come before the found keyword. Any character can occur, but a `\n` should not be followed by a `\r` (as that would indicate the end of the record). The question mark ensures the search is not greedy.

Line 3 matches your keyword.

Line 4 matches what occurs from the keyword until the end of the record. As before the keyword, this can be anything up to the end of the record.

Line 5 establishes what you expect to find after the end of Line 4--either the double line break or the end of the string.

Comment: (?<=^|\n\n)(.|\n(?!\n\n))*?LCD(.|\n(?!\n\n))*(?=\n\n|$)

Comment: Thanks man, You saved me. I tried from last 12 hours for this. You done it.